# Throwing and catch an exception in the same method in Java

Tags: java, oop, exception, coding-style

Our service is calling an API which retrieves data from Database. Lets define it like this

> public List< RowData > getData(int id) throws FinderException

Looking at this API, I thought it would throw FinderException when the data is not found. So, my code is :-

```
try{
    List<RowData> list = getData(id);
} catch (FinderException e) {
     throw new InternalException();
}
return list;
```

Now, I realized that the API is not throwing the FinderException when the data is not found. Hence, my client's code is breaking. Because the clients of our API were expecting the InternalException to be thrown when the data is not found. Now, their code

```
list.get(0)
```

is breaking.
Now, I'm thinking of changing the code to :-

```
try{
    List<RowData> list = getData();
    if(list.isEmpty()) throw new FinderException()
} catch (FinderException e) {
     throw new InternalException();
}
return list;
```

is this good code to throw and catch in the same method? If not, why.
How can I improve my design?

Answer (score 1):

You should handle both cases seperately:

1. FinderException of your API (which is thrown for whatever reason, maybe if the underlying service is unavailable or something).
2. No items found (I suggest you create your own (internal) NoItemsFoundException or something similar)

``

```
List<RowData> list;
try {
    list = getData();
    if(list.isEmpty()) throw new NoItemsFoundException(); 
 // handle this elsewhere, maybe the same place you handle InternalException
} catch (FinderException e) {
    throw new InternalException(e.getMessage());
}
return list;
```

It is good practice to pass the message of the caught FinderException to the rethrown InternalException, so no information is lost.

Comment: InternalException is the NoItemsFoundException

Comment: i understand, but I still would differentiate between the two cases: 1. Item not found, 2. api error. If you really only want to handle 1 Exception, then yes, you can do the solution you proposed. It is ok to catch an exception and rethrow a different one, but then it would be good to pass the original message to your new Exception.